# Retrofit Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException host == null

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit to do some requests to web services, but until recently everything went wrong and I started getting the exception mentioned in the title. I have a base class which basically looks like this:

```
protected BaseService(int version) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    if (cookieJar == null) {
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);
    }

    builder.cookieJar(cookieJar);

    if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
        BASE_URL = "http://nasko.dev.trainingassetsgateway.com";

        builder.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic REMOVED")
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        });

    } else {
        BASE_URL = "https://trainingassetsgateway.com";
    }

    API_URL = BASE_URL + "/mapi/" + version + "/";

    client = new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient = builder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

The problem starts in the interceptor chain. I've traced it to the HttpEngine.createAddress method where a new instance of Address is being created.

[image: createAddress from debugger]

As seen the host part of the URL is there, but later on in the next call in the stack the "uriHost" is null, while it should have been the same thing that is seen in the "Watches" window.

[image: uriHost is null from debugger]

From there it reaches the point where the host is null and the exception is thrown. Am I doing something wrong or maybe missing something?

Comment: does this happen to both urls??

Comment: Yes, it happens to both. It's not from the cookie jar and not from the interceptor also

Comment: use BASE_URL as base url and not API_URL

Comment: Tried that and move the rest of the URL to the service, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever comes into this just delete the app on the phone. I wish I did this sooner...